# Handling operations on generic subclass, referenced as base class, without adding unreasonable clutter

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class that I'm using to represent nodes in a labeled tree structure consisting of a string label, a reference to a Node parent, and an array of Node descendants. Nodes have a function `Combine` which takes another node as an argument and returns a union of the two trees, according to labels.

```
class Node
{
    string name;
    Node parent;
    Node[] descendants;

    //various functions

    public Node Combine(Node B){...}
}
```

I would like to be able to tie values to these nodes, in addition to the label they already have, and have the Combine function act on the values as well (for example, a node labeled 'A' with value '<34' and another labeled 'A' with value '>6' would combine to make a node labeled 'A' with value '(6, 34)'. Some nodes should not have values tied to them, and combining them with a valued node should result in the node carrying over. Values should be able to have various types, with type mismatches either handled by the types in question or throwing a type error at runtime. I first tried to do this by using a byte array for the values and parsing the array whenever I wanted to do anything with them, but it seems to me that the better way to do this in C# would be to use a generic and abstract class like the following:

```
abstract class NodeValue<Sub>
{
    public abstract Sub Combine(Sub B){...}
}

class Node<T>:Node where T:NodeValue<T>
{
    T value;
    public Node<T>(T val):base() { value = val; }
}
```

Ugliness of `NodeValue<Sub>` aside, I can't figure out how to properly define the Combine function. The sensible way to implement it is recursively, which requires that all `Node<T>`'s be referenced as Nodes. Making `Combine` virtual isn't sufficient on it's own, as it would still return a Node rather than the `Node<T>` I need. Adding a `Combine<T>` function that returns `Node<T>` to the Node class would require that I either know ahead of time whether I'm using a `Node` or a `Node<T>`, which requires expensive reflection or a convoluted and error-prone system of dummy variables, or make a nearly identical function with different arguments to handle `Node`, `Node<T>` and `Node<S != T>` inputs, all of which (as well as the original Combine) would need to be overridden in `Node<T>`, resulting in eight almost-but-not-quite-identical methods where one really should suffice.

Am I missing something about how generics can be implemented? I'm pretty sure that generic properties/fields are not allowed, which is what I really want I think, but is there some functionality equivalent to them that I could use?

Comment: Why isn't `Node` generic in the first place? Do you have nodes with different typed values in the same tree? If so, you're not going to solve this with pure generics

Comment: I do indeed want different typed values in the same tree, and am rapidly coming to agree with your last sentence. I'd hoped to delocalize the definition of the type, but it looks like that's not going to happen...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've found a work around that's much cleaner, though not perfect, using delegates and abstract classes, but without Generics.

Define `Node` and `NodeValue` as follows:

```
class Node
{
    string name;
    Node parent;
    Node[] descendants;
    NodeValue val;

    ...

    Node Combine(Node B)
    {
        Node C = new Node();
        C.name = name;
        C.val = val.Combine(B.val);
        ...
    }
}

delegate NodeValue comb(NodeValue B);

abstract class NodeValue
{
    protected readonly int index;
    public comb[] Combinations;

    public NodeValue(int ind, comb[] combs)
    {
        index = ind;
        Combinations = combs;
    }

    public NodeValue Combine(NodeValue B)
    {
        if (B.index > Combinations.Length)
        {
            return null; //could alternately throw an exception, depending on the desired behavior.
        }
        return Combinations[B.index](B);
    }
}
```

Subclasses of `NodeValue` should have constructors that implement `base(n, combs[])` for a specific index `n`, not varying from instance to instance, and should populate `combs[]` with methods that compare it to and return other available types appropriately.